# invalid syntax when trying to use os.path.join in pygame in loading images and sounds

Tags: python, python-3.x, join, pygame

I created a game using pygame and I loaded the images and the sound files using the full path name of the files, but I'd like to make the game executable to run in any location and any other computers.

To that  I replaced the full path name by `os.path.join` to load images and sound files from relative folder.

it was working fine for the first two lines by using it in more lines it gives me this error:

`pygame.mixer.music.set_volume(0.5)
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

So if there a way to let the game load the data from the adjacent folder no matter where it's located, or to know

```
import pygame
import winsound
from pygame.locals import *
import auto_py_to_exe
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
import os
import sys
import time
import random


pygame.init() 
screen_width = 800
screen_height = 500
win = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width,screen_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('Game')


walkRight = [pygame.image.load(os.path.join('data','S1.png')), pygame.image.load(os.path.join('data','S2.png')), pygame.image.load(os.path.join('data','S3.png')), pygame.image.load(os.path.join('data','S4.png')), pygame.image.load(os.path.join('data','S5.png')), pygame.image.load(os.path.join('data','S6.png')), pygame.image.load(os.path.join('data','S7.png')), pygame.image.load(os.path.join('data','S8.png')), pygame.image.load(os.path.join('data','S9.png')), pygame.image.load(os.path.join('data','S10.png')), pygame.image.load(os.path.join('data','S11.png')), pygame.image.load(os.path.join('data','S12.png')), pygame.image.load(os.path.join('data','S13.png')), pygame.image.load(os.path.join('data','S14.png')), pygame.image.load(os.path.join('data','S15.png')), pygame.image.load(os.path.join('data','S16.png')), pygame.image.load(os.path.join('data','S17.png')), pygame.image.load(os.path.join('data','S18.png')), pygame.image.load(os.path.join('data','S19.png')), pygame.image.load(os.path.join('data','S20.png')), pygame.image.load(os.path.join('data','S21.png')), pygame.image.load(os.path.join('data','S22.png')), pygame.image.load(os.path.join('data','S23.png')), pygame.image.load(os.path.join('data','S24.png')), pygame.image.load(os.path.join('data','S25.png')), pygame.image.load(os.path.join('data','S26.png')), pygame.image.load(os.path.join('data','S27.png')), pygame.image.load(os.path.join('data','S28.png')), pygame.image.load(os.path.join('data','S29.png')), pygame.image.load(os.path.join('data','S30.png')), pygame.image.load(os.path.join('data','S31.png')), pygame.image.load(os.path.join('data','S32.png')), pygame.image.load(os.path.join('data','S33.png'))]
walkleft = [pygame.image.load(os.path.join('data','H1.png')), pygame.image.load(os.path.join('data','H2.png')), pygame.image.load(os.path.join('data','H3.png')), pygame.image.load(os.path.join('data','H4.png')), pygame.image.load(os.path.join('data','H5.png')), pygame.image.load(os.path.join('data','H6.png')), pygame.image.load(os.path.join('data','H7.png')), pygame.image.load(os.path.join('data','H8.png')), pygame.image.load(os.path.join('data','H9.png')), pygame.image.load(os.path.join('data','H10.png')), pygame.image.load(os.path.join('data','H11.png')), pygame.image.load(os.path.join('data','H12.png')), pygame.image.load(os.path.join('data','H13.png')), pygame.image.load(os.path.join('data','H14.png')), pygame.image.load(os.path.join('data','H15.png')), pygame.image.load(os.path.join('data','H16.png')), pygame.image.load(os.path.join('data','H17.png')), pygame.image.load(os.path.join('data','H18.png')), pygame.image.load(os.path.join('data','H19.png')), pygame.image.load(os.path.join('data','H20.png')), pygame.image.load(os.path.join('data','H21.png')), pygame.image.load(os.path.join('data','H22.png')), pygame.image.load(os.path.join('data','H23.png')), pygame.image.load(os.path.join('data','H24.png')), pygame.image.load(os.path.join('data','H25.png')), pygame.image.load(os.path.join('data','H26.png')), pygame.image.load(os.path.join('data','H27.png')), pygame.image.load(os.path.join('data','H28.png')), pygame.image.load(os.path.join('data','H29.png')), pygame.image.load(os.path.join('data','H30.png')), pygame.image.load(os.path.join('data','H31.png')), pygame.image.load(os.path.join('data','H32.png')), pygame.image.load(os.path.join('data','H33.png'))]



pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.mixer.Sound(os.path.join('sound','music.wav')
pygame.mixer.music.set_volume(0.5)
pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)



bg = pygame.image.load(os.path.join('data','FOREST.jpg').convert()

'''
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot one parenthesis here `pygame.mixer.Sound(os.path.join('sound','music.wav')`
It must be like this `pygame.mixer.Sound(os.path.join('sound','music.wav'))`